# Calculate height and number of lines of the label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a text that is shown in a `UILabel`. However, this text have several line spaces as shown below. Now, I want to calculate the height of this label, considering the newline, Bold-text and font size. Since this text can not be placed in a Single line in the label, there might be several lines that we must determine at runtime. Based on this height I want to increase the y cordinate of my `UILabel` so the `UILabel` will always be stuck to the bottom of the screen. (Only the height will increase (upwards))

How can I solve this?

```
NSAttributedString *linespace = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"\n"];

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Mathews is a " attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:40]}];  

NSAttributedString*    attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Bad guy"] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:40]}];


[mutableString appendAttributedString: linespace];

[mutableString appendAttributedString: attributed];

[mutableString appendAttributedString: linespace];
```

Comment: i thing Autolayout is better option than calculating the height

Answer (score 0):

You can get height by

```
CGRect rectCountry = [mutableString boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){@“YOUR WIDTH”, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                     context:nil];
CGSize sizeCountry = rectCountry.size;
```